# jQuery validation in Symfony 2

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation, symfony

im trying to get jquery validation to my symfony 2 project for long time. It work fine with default messages. But cant get there custom messages. There is problem with name of inputs. When i try something like this:

```
rules: {
   xxx_backbundle_offerstype[title]: "required"
},messages: {
   xxx_backbundle_offerstype[title]: "This field is required"
}
```

I get this error "missing operator after id". I think, it is JS error, but i dont know, how to solve it.
Is it actually possible, to use jquery validation inf symfony.

Thank you for any tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below, use single quotes

```
rules: {
   'xxx_backbundle_offerstype[title]': "required"
},messages: {
   'xxx_backbundle_offerstype[title]': "This field is required"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you embed your JavaScript in HTML, you could do this (at least I'm doing it this way):

```
rules: {
    '{{ form.foo.vars.full_name }}': 'required'
},
messages: {
    '{{ form.foo.vars.full_name }}': 'This field is required!'
}
```

By doing this, you won't have to update your script when you update your form item's name.